# jQuery: Count words in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following jQuery functionality to count words in real time:

```
$("input[type='text']:not(:disabled)").each(function(){
            var input = '#' + this.id;
            word_count(input);

            $(this).keyup(function(){
                word_count(input);
            })

        });

var word_count = function(field) {
        var number = 0;
        var original_count = parseInt($('#finalcount').val());
        var matches = $(field).val().match(/\b/g);
        if(matches) {
            number = matches.length/2;
        }
        $('#finalcount').val(original_count + number)
    }
```

The issue I am running into is that when I start typing in an input field, the count increases immediately by two, even on spaces and my delete key. Any ideas why this would happen?

I was following this tutorial: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-count-words-textarea-input/

Input:
`<input class="widest" id="page_browser_title" name="page[browser_title]" size="30" type="text" value="">`

Display Input:
`<input class="widest" disabled="disabled" id="finalcount" name="page[word_count]" size="30" type="text" value="662">`

Comment: Can you enter your html also for the input and display div?

Comment: Do you have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Here is a link to jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/M7Jny/

Comment: The fiddle is not running for me - i get `undefined is not a function` in the console. Anyone see it working?

Comment: @adam You have to move the `word_count` declaration above the `each` call.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is incrementing with every key press because you are telling it to with:

```
$('#finalcount').val(original_count + number)
```

And if you add another word, you will find that it increments not by 2, but by 3.  Presumably, you have several inputs on the page, and you intend for the finalcount input to display the number of words in each input.  Either store the counts in a variable and add the variables together to get your finalcount value.  Or count the words in each input every time.

```
var wordCounts = {};

function word_count (field) {
    var number = 0;
    var matches = $(field).val().match(/\b/g);
    if (matches) {
        number = matches.length / 2;
    }
    wordCounts[field] = number;
    var finalCount = 0;
    $.each(wordCounts, function(k, v) {
        finalCount += v;
    });
    $('#finalcount').val(finalCount)
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/YJVPZ/

**Edit:**  By the way, you've got some opportunities to simplify your code a bit by removing some redundancy.  You can replace all of the JavaScript you posted with this:

```
var wordCounts = {};
$("input[type='text']:not(:disabled)").keyup(function() {
    var matches = this.value.match(/\b/g);
    wordCounts[this.id] = matches ? matches.length / 2 : 0;
    var finalCount = 0;
    $.each(wordCounts, function(k, v) {
        finalCount += v;
    });
    $('#finalcount').val(finalCount)
}).keyup();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/YJVPZ/1/

Comment: The only thing I am confused on is the redundant keyup binding.. can you explain that a little?

Comment: `.keyup()` with a function argument passed in binds the keyup event to that function.  But, if you omit the function argument, `.keyup()` triggers the keyup event, calling the bound function.  It is the equivelant of `.trigger("keyup")`.  I included that to match the functionality you had in your code where `word_count()` is called at the same time as the event is bound.

Comment: best answer. how can i write it if i want to count it as 4 words whenever a @ will come?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/URzUL/).

---

Why don't you use `split(" ")` instead of matching and dividing the result? You will have an array containing all your words, the length of the array will be the number of words.

```
var matches = $(field).val().split(" ");
```

Also, why are you adding every time the matches to the old result?

```
$('#finalcount').val(original_count + number)
```

Isn't this adding every time all the words twice?

Comment: You can use `number = matches.filter( function(word) { return word.length > 0}).length;` to avoid counting multiple spaces as words.

Comment: @Jose - thanks for the comment! Doing the match(\b\g) matches exactly what I am looking for, its just not working right on keyup for some reason. Its counting every keyup operation

Comment: @Dennis: nice touch, added to the answer!

Comment: @dennismonsewicz: try removing the addition to original_num in the last line of code. I also had to change the function word_count, making it a normal function instead of storing into a variable.

Comment: This is my new number var; `number = matches.filter(function(word){ word.length > 0 }).length;` for some reason (even though there is an input with a word of five characters in length) its returning 0 if you console.log the number var

Comment: sorry forgot the return in my filter ;)