# Javascript Counting bold and italic in editor tinymce or ckeditor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, ckeditor

how too Counting bold and italic words in editor tinymce or ckeditor.
Anybody can help me?
I do this http://szymoon.nazwa.pl//tinymce/tinymce2/index7.php

But this don't count good.

Comment: +1 for a an example showing the problem. can you show use the javascript code you use to count the bold and italic words. if a word is half bold/half regular - how do you want to count this?

Comment: I fink about this:) and i have too solutions when user do this we can use alert('u can't half bold/half... '); or just add some .replace(/<\/em><\/strong>/g,'</em> </strong>'); . I just fink about it and don't now this will be good solution.

Comment: Did you have any luck? or problems?

Comment: Yes i got this.My script count like i wont! But you now this is my first script i javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You should create plugin for this i think.. Beside that i prefer CKEDITOR. And will give you a push in the right way. (Using Jquery & CKEDITOR) :

```
$("strong", editor.getData()).each(
    function(){
             var counter = 0;
             var matches = this.value.match(/\b/g);
             counter += matches ? matches.length / 2 : 0;
             $('#strongCount').val(counter);
         }
);
```

and:

```
$("i", editor.getData()).each(
    function(){
             var counter = 0;
             var matches = this.value.match(/\b/g);
             counter += matches ? matches.length / 2 : 0;
             $('#strongCount').val(counter);
         }
);
```

The question is, when do you go to fire this function?

If you don't put this within a plugin. You can fire this also from the outside of an CKEDITOR instance. Then use CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstanceName instead of editor.!

Used Source for word counting: [jQuery: Count words in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422192/jquery-count-words-in-real-time)

Notice: Maby you need to extend the first check with the  tag..

Good luck :)