# How to implement a word counter in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, word-count

I'm wanting to implement a real-time word counter in a form. So as a user types into the box, a line below the box updates with the correct number of words.

Here is the relevant form code (my views are .html.haml):

```
= f.semantic_fields_for :student_biography do |fb|
  = fb.inputs :name => "About" do
    = fb.input :short_statement, :label => 'Describe yourself! (25 words) ' , :input_html => {:id => "bio_prof_stmt" }
```

So below this description box, I'd like to count the number of words and display an 'out of 25' notice.

I'm assuming that this is just some javascript I need to add, but I don't know where to proceed from here.

Rails 3.2.11, Ruby 1.9.7

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Count words in real time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422192/jquery-count-words-in-real-time)

Comment: If you found any of the answers helpful, do you mind marking an accepted answer? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be too difficult, you would need a div that had its content updated on the keyup event for the input box:

This is a little bit from memory and may need some adjustment but it should get you on the right path:

```
= fb.input :short_statement, :label => 'Describe yourself! (25 words) ' , :input_html => {:id => "bio_prof_stmt" }, :onkeyup => "update_word_count(this);"
```

I think this is the right haml syntax, please correct me if not:

```
#word-count-container
```

The intended html:

```
<div id="word-count-container"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function update_word_count(object) {
    words = object.value.match(/\S+/g).length.toString();
    $('#word-count-container').innerHTML = words + " out of 25 used";
  }
</script>
```

Alternative UJS approach (remove the onkeyup tag from the input):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#short_statement').onkeyup(function() { 
      update_word_count(this);
  });

  function update_word_count(object) {
    words = object.value.match(/\S+/g).length.toString();
    $('#word-count-container').innerHTML = words + " out of 25 used";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is a great approach! However, I would take an unobtrusive javascript route, rather than declaring the event in HTML.

Comment: @GranvilleSchmidt I was wanting to do that too. To which .js file would I add this?

Comment: @XMLSlayer I would add it to the javascript file that corresponds to the controller.

Comment: @XMLSlayer I suggested an edit to Matt's response, that uses an unobtrusive approach. I just used generic js methods, as I didn't know what js framework you were using.

Comment: Thank you @GranvilleSchmidt , I don't know how to accept that edit though, if I can?

Comment: @XMLSlayer I've added a UJS approach to the answer, I hope it helps! I'm a little less experienced in UJS but I think it's correct.

Comment: Hi @XMLSlayer how did you get on with this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something that you have to validate on the server side as well as the client side. So don't forget to do that.

```
validates :short_statement, length: { maximum: 25 }
```

If you want strict word counting you can use the [Words Counted](https://github.com/abitdodgy/words_counted) gem. Disclaimer I wrote it.