# word counting Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is the script for counting words.

1. Can it be made simple?
2. on deleting all or partial of the words it does not update the values. i tried but could not come up with anything. How can it be done?
3. "Can it be made simple?" This shall be counted as FIVE words. But check this [without quotes] this script copunts it SIX. What is wrong?

HTML
     **Message:**
    
    Total word Count : 0 words.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#word_count').wordCount();
});

jQuery.fn.wordCount = function (params) {
    var p = {
        counterElement: "display_count"
    };
    var total_words;

    if (params) {
        jQuery.extend(p, params);
    }

    //for each keypress function on text areas
    this.keypress(function () {
        total_words = this.value.split(/[\s\.\?]+/).length;
        jQuery('#' + p.counterElement).html(total_words);
    });
};
```

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ZmbxS/

Comment: Bind your function to `change()` instead of keypress.

Comment: `console.log()` to see which words it's counting. Maybe your regex is wrong.

Comment: Also, in my test, I'm seeing 5 words: http://puu.sh/3JNh1.png

Comment: @Seiyria - change would only fire when the input loses focus.

Comment: ITYM the `input` event.

Comment: There are a decent number of jquery word counters out there already (http://bavotasan.com/2011/simple-textarea-word-counter-jquery-plugin/ for example).  Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: This didn't help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422192/jquery-count-words-in-real-time#7422464

Comment: @Seiyria strange. I always keep getting 6 for the same.

Comment: @user2057047 I am using Chrome, but I don't know how that would change your RegEx.

Comment: @BenBarden I am not looking for what you gave the link. You provided a limit counter. I am looking for word counter.

Answer (score 6):

> Can it be made simple?

sure can, use a word boundary matching anything that isn't whitespace :

```
$('#word_count').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#display_count').text(this.value.split(/\b\S+\b/g).length-1)
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmbxS/2/)

and it seems like a wasted use of a plugin for something that can be done that easily ?

Comment: It's not quite that simple. What about hyphenated words, or words that contain an apostrophe?

Comment: @CrazyTrain - what about them? Did you try it in the provided fiddle ?

Comment: No, I tested in the console. Why is there a different result? EDIT: ...oh, I think I forgot the `-1`. My apologies. +1

Comment: if i add word like this.. "what the ? fcuk" without quotes. It shall show 4 words. but it show only 3. How can it be changed?

Answer (score 0):

See this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmbxS/1/)

1. You need to "trim" your value to ensure that there are no leading/trailing spaces (which produce mentioned +1)
2. I've attached this handler to `keyup` event instead.

Code:

```
this.keyup(function () {
    my_value = this.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
    total_words = my_value.split(/[\s\.\?]+/).length;
    jQuery('#' + p.counterElement).html(total_words);
});
```

Comment: but when all are deleted, it left 1 instead of 0. try that.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a matter on the event you're using. I'd suggest you to bind the function to the change event.

For the regexp, it is not enough to make the split just by?:

```
stringValue.split(/\s/);
```

Best regards.