# How to count number of words in a textfield

Tags: javascript, html

I have a user enter biograpgy in a text box html for that is

```
<p>Biography:
            <input type="text" id="biography" name="biography"   /> 
            <span id="biographyInvalid" style="color:red; visibility:hidden"> Biography is Invalid </span>
        </p>
```

for Javascript i have a checkme function that is called and i want to do a check inside of it

```
function checkme(){

    var biography=document.getElementById('biography').value;
}
```

how can i count number of words, do i first convert it to string and then separate with spaces

Comment: Looks like this question has already bee answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422192/jquery-count-words-in-real-time

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<div id="count">145</div>
<div id="barbox"><div id="bar"></div></div>
</div>
<textarea id="contentbox"></textarea>
```

and js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#contentbox").keyup(function()
{
var box=$(this).val();
var main = box.length *100;
var value= (main / 145);
var count= 145 - box.length;

if(box.length <= 145)
{
$('#count').html(count);
$('#bar').animate(
{
"width": value+'%',
}, 1);
}
else
{
alert(' Full ');
}
return false;
});

});
</script>


$('#contentbox').keyup(function(){} - contentbox is the ID of the textbox.
 Using $(this).val() getting the textbox value. 
bar is the div ID of the count meter $('#bar').animate() increasing the width.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   js:    
   $('#biography').keyup(function () {
   var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
   $('#count').html('Words Count:'+words);
   });
  HTML:

 <div id="count"></div>
```

This gives you correct words count

Answer (score 0):

This is working example 
the HTML

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="">
<textarea name="inpString" cols="80" rows="4"  onkeyup="countNoOfWords()"  >This is a sample text that has been typed to count the number of words it contains. Click the button below to find out.</textarea>
<br />
  <input name="noofwords" type="text" value="" size="6" />
</form>
```

The JS function

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function countNoOfWords(){
 document.myform.noofwords.value = document.myform.post_content.value.split(' ').length;
}
</script>
```

[reference](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/count-number-words-using-javascript)

Answer (score -2):

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
   var cs = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
   $('#biography').text(cs);
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/hNn5b/685/

Comment: This counts characters.